# Prove that $ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)=L \leftrightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}[f(x)-L]=0 $

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval, $c \in I$, and
$f:I-\left \{ c \right \} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function with $L \in \mathbb{R}$. Using only the definition of limits, prove that,
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)=L \leftrightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}[f(x)-L]=0 $$

Comment: Have you written out what the definitions of the two mean?

Comment: I did. I apologize

Comment: So, $|x-c|<\delta \rightarrow |(f(x)-L)-0| < \epsilon$. And now I need to choose a value for delta? What value could I choose?

Answer (score 2):

The crucial observation is that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ is equivalent to $|(f(x)-L)-0|<\epsilon$.

Comment: What value would I choose for $\delta$ though?

Comment: Assume the first one hold, the $\delta>0$ has been chosen for the corresponding $\epsilon>0$, and this $\delta$ can be used for the second one, no need to change.

Comment: Ok, So I start with $|x-c|<\delta$ with $\delta = \epsilon$? I'm sorry but I'm having trouble understanding.

Comment: No, do not take $\delta$ to be $\epsilon$, this $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$, you cannot change it, the crucial point is that, for $x$ with $0<|x-c|<\delta$ that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ holds, then such an $x$ still makes $|(f(x)-L)-0|<\epsilon$ holds, so this proves the left to right direction.